# AndroidFFMPEG Appunite library issue

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-videoview, android-video-player

I am facing some with [androidFfmpeg library](https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg) on video seek.

Can anyone help me out on this reported issue.
[jni_player_seek problem](https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg/issues/50)

Comment: Are you encoding the videos you are viewing?

Comment: No. I am directly playing it using ffmpeg player that inside AndroidFFmpeg.

Comment: And using all the native methods like stop,seek etc. which is defined in jni

Answer (score 1):

If I saw that correctly, the Android FFMPEG library uses android.widget.SeekBar in its [VideoActivity](https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg/blob/master/FFmpegExample/src/com/ffmpegtest/VideoActivity.java) .

You might have to call the method onFFUpdateTime(long currentTimeUs, long videoDurationUs, boolean isFinished) or implement a seekbar yourself according to this [tutorial](http://united-coders.com/nico-heid/an-android-seekbar-for-your-mediaplayer/).

Comment: That's fine I have used that. But what happens inside is it call player.seekNative(params[0].longValue()) which is in FFmpegPlayer.java  and this seekNative is not returning video frame sequentially on moving the video backward.

Comment: On Seeking the video for large amount of time, The video takes time to load and seek bar flutter ........ Is there any way for smoothing the frames on seeking.

Comment: The FFmpegPlayer#seekNative is calling "private native void seekNative(int position) throws NotPlayingException;" . Using some JNI magic there, it seems. so if you have to change that behaviour, you'll have to find out what native method it is calling, or define that seekbar yourself, I'd say.
But I can't figure out what exactly that method is calling there. You'll have to get a grasp on someone with more experience with that Player.

Comment: I have gone inside all its jni calls and tried to modify the seek in the C code but it has so many mutex declaration. Very difficult to understand what is happening inside. Please someone guide me what should I do ..

Answer (score 0):

Currently player_seek is using Asynchtask, You should run play_seek on main thread, do not use Asynchtask.

I am running on main thread and player_seek is working as expecting.